# How to use Twitter Bootstrap plugins with jQuery 1.6.2?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using couple of twitter bootstrap plugins like Typeahead and Tooltip. For some reason I had to move to older version of jQuery (1.6.2) but now these bootstrap plugins are failing.

Is there a way to make Bootstrap plugins work with jQuery 1.6.2 ?

Comment: Are you using it through the data attributes or through a call to the .typeahead() ?

Comment: I'm using it through call to typeahead() method.

Comment: Ok, i figured something out: many of the plugins are using .on() to bind events, but on was added in 1.7. So you have to write a wrapper to the .on function with the same signature. I dunno if there is something else, but this would be a try...

Comment: Thanks. I think, I should convert it to "delegate". http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: That is the answer, but I will write a little plugin that will create the behaviour of .on() for older versions of jQuery

Comment: I just replaced .on with .bind and .delegate (.bind wherever event was bind to that specific element and .delegate wherever it was bind to it's child) and it worked. 

Thanks for the hint. :)